# Get date where RESULT is processed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below table.

[image: Table]

In the above table I need the New Date populated based on the Comments, Date, RESULT columns. I need the dates populated only for the PROCESSED Result columns.

So in the above table.. The highlighted color comments column should match with highlighted new date column. The date and new date column are same.. just highlighted with same color.

If the current record is processed and the next record is not processed, I need to find the date of the last not_processed record before a processed record begins. If the next record is processed then the current record date should be the new_date.

Thanks in Advance!!

I tried using rank, Lead functions but couldn't get any logic correct

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row processing and a `MERGE` statement to update the table:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT rowid rid, new_dt
  FROM   table_name
  MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
    PARTITION BY id
    ORDER     BY dt DESC, result DESC
    MEASURES
      FIRST(dt) AS new_dt
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    PATTERN (not_processed* processed )
    DEFINE
      processed     AS result = 'PROCESSED',
      not_processed AS result = 'NOT_PROCESSED'
  )
  WHERE result = 'PROCESSED'
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET new_date = new_dt;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(id, dt, result, new_date) AS
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-02-26', 'PROCESSED',     CAST(NULL AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-05', 'NOT_PROCESSED', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-05', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-05', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-12', 'NOT_PROCESSED', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-13', 'NOT_PROCESSED', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-20', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-21', 'NOT_PROCESSED', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-21', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-21', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, DATE '2023-03-28', 'PROCESSED',     NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| ID | DT | RESULT | NEW_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-02-26 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-05 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-05 00:00:00 | NOT_PROCESSED | *null* |
| 123 | 2023-03-05 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-05 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-05 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-12 00:00:00 | NOT_PROCESSED | *null* |
| 123 | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 | NOT_PROCESSED | *null* |
| 123 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 | NOT_PROCESSED | *null* |
| 123 | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 123 | 2023-03-28 00:00:00 | PROCESSED | 2023-03-28 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kxaXx-gT)

Answer (score 1):

This combination of analytic functions and `case ... when`  gave me correct output:

```
select rn, dt, result, grp,
       case 
       when result = 'P' 
         and (lead(result) over (partition by id order by rn) = 'P' or
              lead(result) over (partition by id order by rn) is null ) 
       then dt
       when result = 'P' and lead(result) over (partition by id order by rn) = 'N'
       then max(dt) over (partition by id, grp)  
       end new_dt
  from (
     select row_number() over (partition by id order by dt, result) rn, 
            id, dt, result,
            count(case result when 'P' then 1 end) 
                  over (partition by id order by dt, result) grp
     from t )
  order by rn
```

**[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oez0HbOg)**